# I use 'exit(EXIT_FAILURE);', but then I get an error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I write like this.
error say "c:17:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘exit’"
but change to 'exit(1)' then only say warning but running.
why I can not use 'exit(EXIT_FAILURE);'?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define EXIT_FAILURE /*implementation defined*/
#define EXIT_SUCCESS /*implementation defined*/

int main(void)
{
    char *swd;
    int ret;

    swd = getcwd(NULL,0);
    printf("1.%s\n",swd);
    printf("2.%s\n",getcwd(NULL,0));

    if(!swd){
        perror("getcwd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
    }
    ret = chdir("dd");
    //printf("3.%s\n",ret);
    printf("4.%s\n",getcwd(NULL,0));
    if(ret){
        perror("chdir");
    }
    ret = chdir(swd);
    printf("5.%s\n",getcwd(NULL,0));
    enter code here
    if(ret){
        perror("chdir");
        exit(1);
    }
    free(swd);
}
```

Comment: You have defined `EXIT_FAILURE` to mean nothing, so the compiler sees `exit()`. Include `<stdlib.h>` for the implementation defined definition of `EXIT_FAILUE`. (Implementation defined refers to the implementation of the compiler, not your program.)

Comment: @MOehm: I was going to post this as an aswer, but you did it as a comment before me. And this is exactly correct answer to this question.

Comment: @running.t: I made it only a comment, because it seemed such a trivial problem. If you write it as an answer, I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in comments you have defined `EXIT_FAILURE` to be nothing and by the way `EXIT_FAILURE` is defined in `stdlib.h` so you need not define it you just include it and use it. If you like to define it your self do like this :

`#define EXIT_FAILURE -1 /* A number not equal to 0 */
 #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0`